# Xamarin Forms XAML ContextAction Binding to C# in ViewCell

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML working to bind to a delete command in my view model:

```
        <TextCell.ContextActions>
          <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCollectionCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=CollectionListView}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    Text="Delete" 
                    IsDestructive="True" />
        </TextCell.ContextActions>
```

I'm trying to convert it to C# so I can programmatically use it.

I've tried the following but it's not working. What needs to be changed? Is there a better/different way to access the ViewModel DeleteCommand?

```
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background
        deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
        deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty,
            new Binding("BindingContext.DeleteCommand", BindingMode.Default, null, null, null, "{x:Reference Name=CollectionBeerListView}"));

        ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);
    }
```

**EDIT**

I was able to get this working by combining skar's answer and initializing the Cell like this from the parent view:

```
        lstView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var cell = new DeleteGenericListItemTemplate(page);
            return cell;
        });
```

Not sure if this is ideal.. but keeps me moving.

Comment: Well I do not know how to make a binding throw C# with Xaml is much easier and straight forward and I have to say this is the strangest binding I have seen.
I can help you with the second part of your question . 
To reach the property you need in the viewmodel , you need to set the BindingContext = new  (your_ViewModel) . when you do this you can bind to it easier . 
Can you share more of the codebehind and the Xaml so we can help you better. One more question why do you want to do it with C# instead of Xaml ?

Comment: I need to be able to programmatically show/hide the Delete Action which is why I'm doing it from C#. This is a Generic View Cell I'm using in multiple places.

Comment: I need to access the View Model's "Delete Command" from within the context of a given View Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you extend on the text cell to create something like below with a reference to your page you should be able to access your DeleteCommand on your ViewModel through the binding context of the page:

```
public class CustomCell: TextCell
{
        public CustomCell(Page page)
        {
            var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background
            deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
            deleteButton.SetBinding (MenuItem.CommandProperty, new Binding ("BindingContext.DeleteCommand", source: page));
            ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);


        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I need to actually pass the "Page" object in? If so, How would I call this custom cell from XAML passing that variable?

Comment: you would have to use code behind I think. Just like the new edit you have put on your post.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a ParentContext property to my (custom) viewcell. Set that property to the ViewModel by using the AncestorType, like this:

```
ParentContext="{Binding ., Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyViewModel}}}"
```

My custom viewcell:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ParentContextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ParentContext", typeof(object), typeof(CustomViewCell), null, BindingMode.OneTime);
    public object ParentContext
    {
        get { return GetValue(ParentContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParentContextProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then in my viewcell i added the contextaction by reference to the viewcell x:Name and it works :)

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
<MenuItem 
    Command="{Binding ParentContext.TheCommand, Source={x:Reference customViewCellName}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
    Text="Some text">
</MenuItem>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```